# Cannot resolve method 'openFile(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class hello {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        File file = new File("example.txt");

        try {
            openFile("example.txt");
       } catch (FileNotFoundException exception){

            System.out.println("Cannot find that file");

        }

    }
}
```

java : cannot find symbol 
symbol : method openFile(java.lang.String)

Cannot resolve method 'openFile(java.lang.String)'

EDİTED (thanks for our helps)

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class hello {
            public static void main(String [] args) {

try{
    File file = new File("example.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("opened");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("Cannot find that file");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you don't have `openFile` method, you mean `new File("example.txt");` ?

Comment: The error means that you do not have a method named `openFile` in your class `hello`. You'll need to add that method yourself, or if it's in another class, call it correctly.

Comment: Is this your full code? If you want to use a "openFile" method, you will need to define it first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to assume a few things here. Given that its a text file and you're trying to open it, I'm guessing you're trying to read it,if not then edit your question.

You need a bufferedReader, you can probably find an implementation for your specific case but the basics are:

1. create a buffered reader (called "reader" for example)
2. Use the following line:

   ```
   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   ```

   Where file is the path to the .txt file.
3. Then to read do use

   ```
   reader.readLine());
   ```

   Put a while loop around this where the condition is that reader.readLine is not null 
   and also put a try/catch around it.

Hope this helps, I'm making a few assumptions but reading a .txt file is quite common and it looks like that's what you're trying to do.